# Warning: Signed shift result (0x1F0000000) requires 34 bits to represent, but 'int' only has 32 bits

Tags: ios, sqlite

After compiling the [reMail](https://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) project with no error, one of the warnings is:

> remail-iphone/sqlite3/sqlite3.c:18703:15: Signed shift result
>   (0x1F0000000) requires 34 bits to represent, but 'int' only has 32
>   bits

i.e. `(0x1f<<28)` in the following code:

```
  if (!(a&0x80))
  {
    a &= (0x1f<<28)|(0x7f<<14)|(0x7f);
    b &= (0x7f<<14)|(0x7f);
    b = b<<7;
    a |= b;
    s = s>>11;
    *v = ((u64)s)<<32 | a;
    return 7;
  }
```

What's the proper way to kill this warning for iOS (32-bit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reMail for iPhone seems to be using an old version of SQLite (3.6.15). If I'm not mistaken, the following commit should fix exactly this problem: http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/587109c81a9cf479?sbs=0

```
if (!(a&0x80))
{
    /* assert( ((0xFF<<28)|(0x7f<<14)|(0x7f))==0xf01fc07f ); */
    a &= 0xf01fc07f;
    b &= (0x7f<<14)|(0x7f);
    b = b<<7;
    a |= b;
    s = s>>11;
    *v = ((u64)s)<<32 | a;
    return 7;
}
```

However, there might be other code sections where this problem occurs. The mentioned link shows two instances in util.c, but since sqlite.c is "an amalgamation of many separate C source files from SQLite", you may find additional occurences.
Maybe reMail would work with a recent version of SQLite, too...